# Power keeps cutting out to hot tub

Tags: electrical, hot-tub

I have an outdoor Hydropool hot tub and have recently been having an issue with power.  It seems that periodically a build up of 'gunk' (my technical term for it) builds up around one of the electrical connections to the heater and eventually causes the breaker to trip.

In the past I have been able to fix the problem by simply disconnecting the wires and wiping away the gunk with some paper towel.  This typically happens only after quite intense rain storms but I'm not sure if it's related.

Is there a way to keep this from happening?  or is it a sign of something more significant going on that I should get checked out.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that this "gunk" keeps building up is a sign that there is an underlying cause you've not found.

I'd get an electrician with hot tub experience to take a look. It might be something simple, but with electricity **and** water you don't want to get it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly water is getting into the connection, and that's bad.  Look for the source of the water, how is it getting in, and is there something failing to prevent it that's supposed (like a clogged drain nearby, or faulty gaskets).

Depending on where those connections are, the root probably may be a plumbing, and not electrical.

If the root problem isn't obvious and easy to fix, call an expert.  I'd probably be inclined to start with someone who advertises working on hot tubs from a pool place instead of the electrician, but that would also depend on the price for getting someone to come out and take a look.

Comment: what is "plumping"?